# No me funcionan las sesiones PHP en el servidor

Tags: php, session

He buscado información que me ayude con este caso en particular, pero no he podido encontrar el problema...

Tengo un sitio de uso personal en un hosting compartido que logro acceder a él mediante el panel de Plesk Obsidian y a la hora de desarrollar el login todo va perfecto pero cuando defino y uso las cookies de sesión  `session_start(); $_SESSION['user'] = 'Pedro';` en la pagina siguiente que es la que accede el usuario luego de comprobar sus credenciales, no logro recibir dicha variable definida.
Cabe destacar que el otro archivo .php vuelvo a iniciar el `session_start();`

Codigo del login.php

```
session_start();
  $_SESSION['user'] = 'Juan';

  header("Location: ".SERVERURL."principal/");
  die() ;
```

Codigo principal.php

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();

    //Si existe la sesión "user"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
      $text=$_SESSION['user'];
    }else{
 header('Location: '.SERVERURL);//Aqui lo redireccionas al login para no ingresar a este apartado sino esta autenticado.
     die() ;

    }
?>
```

He llegado a pensar que mi problema viene siendo el php instalado en el servidor que contrato y tiene esta información.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las sesiones PHP se envían como headers, por lo que tendrás que iniciar la sesión antes de enviar cualquier header

```
<?php
   session_start();
//Si existe la sesión "user"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
      $text=$_SESSION['user'];
    }else{
 header('Location: '.SERVERURL);//Aqui lo redireccionas al login para no ingresar a este apartado sino esta autenticado.
     die() ;

    }
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
```

Tienes que enviar los headers de redirección también antes de especificar que el documento es `text/html`

Además si buscas optimizar el SEO, puedes usar la redirección 301 (Redirección permanente)

```
<?php
   session_start();
//Si existe la sesión "user"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
      $text=$_SESSION['user'];
    }else{
 header('Location: '.SERVERURL, true, 301);//Aqui lo redireccionas al login para no ingresar a este apartado sino esta autenticado.
     die() ;

    }
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
```

**NOTA:** Para que esto funcione, tendrás que poner el código PHP **antes de `<!doctype html>`** o cualquier otro tipo de `header`, de lo contrario, el servidor no podrá reenviar headers que ya se enviaron

Ejemplo: Si ya pusiste `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` y en el HTML pones un header que haga que el archivo sea `text/plain` esto no se ejecutará ya que los headers ya han sido enviados y la página se ha cargado, por ese motivo, la página no puede aceptar headers que sean diferentes a los que haya cargado y reportará un error

Comment: Agradecido hermano, mi problema radicaba en el envío de los headers.