# Validar que el usuario tiene permisos para ver la pagina web

Tags: php

Cordial saludo.
Diseñando mi sitio web con PHP, e notado algo que no es correcto. En la primera pagina, el usuario ingresas sus datos (usuario y contraseña). Luego de que es validado en la base de datos identificando que existe, se le da acceso a la pagina del menú que le permite hacer consultas a la base de datos. Al copiar la URL de la pagina donde esta el menú, note que se puede ingresar sin hacer la validación de usuario y contraseña. Entonces pensé, que pasaría si el usuaria le comparte la URL de la pagina donde esta el menú a otra persona que no tiene permisos? pues ingresara a los datos.

He pensado en ponerle una validación también a la pagina del menú utilizando session_start(), que me permitirá conservar las variables del usuario ingresadas en la primera pagina y si este no había ingresado nada (trato de ingresar directamente a la  URL de la pagina del menú) le saldrá un mensaje como "Debe ingresar sus datos de usuario".

Al intentar hacer dicha validación, note que no me era fácil y pensé, posiblemente haya alguna forma mas practica de hacer lo que estoy intentado.

Agradezco las indicaciones que me puedan brindar.

Comment: El principio es ese. Cuando el usuario loguea positivamente almacenas un token en sesión y al cargar cada página compruebas si existe ese token, en caso de hacerlo le sirves la página en cuestión, en caso de no hacerlo le rediriges a la página de "Sesión caducada".

Comment: Es facil validar una sesión y su nivel de acceso. Pero para ello debes mostrar que estás intentando para saber si lo haces bien o no.

Comment: Debes validar si existe una sesión abierta antes de entrar a cualquier página, de esa forma, cualquiera podría entrar, pero si no se ha logueado, entonces no puede acceder a la información

Comment: Veo que tienes varias ideas. Mi sugerencia siempre será: prueba, revisa qué funciona, qué falla y vuelve acá con los problemas que tienes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te lo dijeron en los comentarios, necesitas una sesión

Si documentas el [manual de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php) podrás ver que esto se hace con la variable `$_SESSION`, variable única del servidor y no obtenible desde el cliente

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION["username"])) {
    header("Location: login.php", true, 301);
    die();
}
?>
```

**Explicando:**

El método `session_start()` inicia una sesión o reanuda la que ya ha sido iniciada, es importante que esta vaya antes de la declaración del documento (`!DOCTYPE HTML`) para que se ejecute, ya que esta es un `header` (Puedes encontrar una explicación más amplia de headers [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/419160/no-me-funcionan-las-sesiones-php-en-el-servidor/419168#419168))

Luego, validaremos si dentro de la sesión existe `username`, si no existe, redireccionaremos al usuario a `login.php`, con una redirección `301` (Redirección permanente)

Es importante el `die()` para detener la ejecución del script si el usuario no está logeado y prevenir `error_log`

Tu sesión se podrá acceder desde tu dominio, NO incluye subdominios

Puedes asignar variables de sesión de la siguiente manera

```php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"] = "valor";
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la informacion.

Answer (score 1):

Es conveniente, asegurarte de validar las credenciales en cada una de las páginas que correspondan a una sesión para evitar posibles SQL Injection.

En el siguiente código, si la sesión no se ha validado, el programa enviará al usuario a la página de Login hasta que las credenciales sean validadas por parte del sistema y el usuario haya iniciado sesión.

Acuérdate de incluir siempre session_start() si quieres hacer uso de las variables de sesión que establezcas.

```
<?php
  
session_start();
 
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
  header("location: login.php");

  exit;
}

    require_once "config.php";

?>
```

Convendría que subieras fragmentos de tu código para que así pudiésemos ayudarte de una forma mucho más precisa.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias Nick, excelente aporte.